# External URL to load inside the frame

Tags: android, external-url

I have an issue with my android app not loading the correct content.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Loading your HTML as per PhoneGap tutorial
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 20000);
    super.setIntegerProperty("splashscreen", R.drawable.splashscreen);


    //External URL to load inside the frame
    super.loadUrl("https://news.google.com/", 3000);

    //Internal website to load inside the frame
    //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html", 3000);
}
```

What do I need to place in the code above instead of `https://news.google.com` for the correct content/URL to load?